# How can I use 'Not Like' operator in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, sql-like

I can use the SQL `Like` Operator using `pymongo`,

```
db.test.find({'c':{'$regex':'ttt'}})
```

But how can I use `Not Like` Operator?

I tried

```
db.test.find({'c':{'$not':{'$regex':'ttt'}})
```

but got error:

> OperationFailure: $not cannot have a regex

Comment: I know this is a tiny bit late but in MongoDB 4.2 the `$not` and `$regex` operator in combination seems to work for me.

Comment: `db.collectionname.find( { column: { $not: /^ttt$/ } } )`

Comment: `$not` and `$regex` can be used together starting with MongoDB 4.0.7.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

> The $not operator does not support operations with the $regex
> operator. Instead use // or in your driver interfaces, use your
> language’s regular expression capability to create regular expression
> objects. Consider the following example which uses the pattern match
> expression //:

```
db.inventory.find( { item: { $not: /^p.*/ } } )
```

**EDIT** (@idbentley):

`{$regex: 'ttt'}` is generally equivalent to `/ttt/` in mongodb, so your query would become:

```
db.test.find({c: {$not: /ttt/}}
```

**EDIT2** (@KyungHoon Kim):

In **python**, below one works:

```
'c':{'$not':re.compile('ttt')}
```

Comment: To be clear,  `{$regex: 'ttt'}` is generally equivalent to `/ttt/` in mongodb, so your query would become `db.test.find({c: {$not: /ttt/}}`.

Comment: @idbentley thank you. I updated my answer with your clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much. For other people, I used `'c':{'$not':re.compile('ttt')}`. Of course, you need import re

Comment: Great. I also added your comment to the answer, for posterity.

Comment: This seems to be the same case with $ne and $regex. Can anyone confirm this, or at least add to it?

Answer (score 79):

You can do with regex which does not contain a word. Also, you can use `$options => i` for case of insensitive search.

Doesn't Contain `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^((?!string).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Exact case insensitive `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Starts with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Ends with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Contains `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Keep this as a bookmark, and a reference for any other alterations you may need.
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/