# Mongodb Query contains # char

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can i use $regex for matching any string contains '#'. Unlike other characters, # seems to be acting differently.

```
{"id" : {$regex : "what should go here"}}
```

does match strings that does not contains # as well. I was trying with `.*\\#.*` kind of regex.

Comment: and what you tried instead of "what should go here"? what you get, and what expected?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `#` into a character class `[#]`?

Comment: @2oppin Yes edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
{"id" : {$regex : /^.*#.*/ }}
```

And for `NOT` contains:

```
{"id" : {$not : /^.*#.*/ }}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)

[Reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175122/how-can-i-use-not-like-operator-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

Found out that it should be like this.

```
 {"id" : {$regex : /\#/i}}
```

Comment: From the documentation, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match