# How to create a RegExp for node/mongo that will find data that DOESN'T contain the RegExp

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I want to search a mongo database with a `RegExp`, but instead of returning data with the matched `RegExp` I want to return data that does not have the `RegExp`.

For example:

Find all data that does not contain a `new RegExp("mediaType")`.

I have really bad knowledge of RegExp so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I came across this pattern [^((?!badword).)*$](https://www.regextester.com/15). I cannot explain it hence why I leave it as a comment.

Comment: @Mikey that is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat). It matches any character `.` until it finds `badword`, then it stops.

Comment: @ctwheels Good know!

Comment: @ctwheels is it okay to use ?

Comment: @TaylorAustin it is ok to use but I'm sure there are better ways. I'm not too familiar with mongodb, unfortunately, so my help is limited here. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175122/how-can-i-use-not-like-operator-in-mongodb) contains relevant information for what you're trying to accomplish though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find elements matching a regexp (e.g. *pattern*) you can use:

```
db.coll.find({ fieldName: { $regex: /pattern/ } });
```

To find elements NOT matching the same regexp you can use:

```
db.coll.find({ fieldName: { $not: /pattern/ } });
```

Comment: so would `db.coll.find({ description: {$not: /mediaType/ })` find me all data with description not containing `"mediaType"` ?

Comment: @TaylorAustin you should be able to use `/mediaType/` but you may want to use `/^.*mediaType/` instead (not sure which will perform better - depends on your data)

Comment: @TaylorAustin `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the line and `.*` matches any character (except newline `\n`) any number of times. But you should also just be able to use `mediaType`