# Using $not $in $regex in PyMongo

Tags: python, regex, django, mongodb, pymongo

I want to do a PyMongo equivalent to `vendor NOT IN ('Amazon', 'eBay', 'AliBaba')`.

I am able to get it to work in MongoDB by doing:

```
'vendor': {'$not': {'$in': [/^Amazon/, /^eBay/, /^AliBaba/]}}
```

This works.

In PyMongo no matter what I try, I am getting no result. It is not throwing any errors but not returning any results either.

Here is what I have tried:

1)

```
import re
vendor = {'$not': {'$in': [re.compile('^Amazon'), re.compile('^eBay'), re.compile('^AliBaba')]}}
```

2)

```
import re
vendor = {'$not': {'$in': [re.compile('.*Amazon.*'), re.compile('.*eBay.*'), re.compile('.*AliBaba.*')]}}
```

What am I missing? Why can't I get `not in` work with PyMongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe you are trying to design an expression that'd be somewhat close to:

```
^(?!.*\b(Amazon|eBay|AliBaba)\b).*$
```

not sure though.

Or maybe:

```
.*?\bAmazon\b.*
.*?\beBay\b.*
.*?\bAliBaba\b.*
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jNtFVe/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/jNtFVe/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

and our code might look like:

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^(?!.*\b(Amazon|eBay|AliBaba)\b).*$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

#### Reference

[How can I use 'Not Like' operator in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175122/how-can-i-use-not-like-operator-in-mongodb)